# Talking to one's wife over the Internet and finding pleasure in that

Tags: halal-haram, husband-wife, masturbation

The following site mentions a fatwa that it is permissible for a married couple to talk about sex on the telephone and provoke one another until one or both of them reaches climax, without using the hands.

https://islamqa.info/en/answers/108872/talking-to-ones-wife-over-the-internet-and-finding-pleasure-in-that

**My questions**

1. Is that really permissible for husband and wife to reach climax without using hands on phone or video call?
2. How can they reach to climax without using hands?

Answer (score -1):

why would it not be permissible? they're married. touching oneself is haraam. Unless there is fear of zina.

Comment: Is there any reference to this answer. And how come any of them can discharge while having sex talk but without using their hands? I am just asking in detail because I really want to understand. I am not arguing so don't feel bad.

Comment: Why is touching oneself haraam while married?!